# How do you iterate through two list and count the true positive

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate through a list of predictions and ground truths and count the true positives.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
    tp = 0
    for p, g in zip(predicted, ground_truth):
        if p and g == True: 
           tp += 1
        return tp
```

I am getting an error message saying: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. But the return is inside the function.

Comment: I don't see a function, only a for-loop

Comment: If you want help with your error, you'll need to include more of your code.  Anyhow, you should probably be using something like [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) instead of looping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def count_true(predicted, ground_truth):
    tp = 0
    for p, g in zip(predicted, ground_truth):
        if p and g == True: 
           tp += 1
    return tp

count= count_true([True, False, True], [True, True, False])
print(count)
```

This should return:
`1`

You need to declare a function with `def`

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_true(predicted, ground_truth):
   tp = 0
    for p, g in zip(predicted, ground_truth):
        if p and g == True: 
           tp += 1
        return tp
```

You need to define a function, `def count_true(p, g)`

Comment: Typo: arguments gotta be `predicted` and `ground_truth`. Not `p` and `g`.